# Can I run Webflow 1.0 flows through Spring Webflow 2.1.1?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

I have a project built with Webflow 1.0 and Spring 2.0.  We'd like to upgrade to Spring 3, but that requires Webflow 2.X.

I've updated all the Spring and Webflow jars in the project, but when I try to load the initial flow, I get:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [executor]
```

Other forums have suggested this is due to running a SWF 1.0 flow under SWF 2.X.  **This is exactly what I'm trying to do**, and would like to continue to do, at least until I can test for any issues related directly to the Spring upgrade.

**Is it possible to run SWF 1.0 flows under SWF 2.1.1?**

Comment: You'll likely get better response from the WebFlow forum: http://forum.springsource.org/forumdisplay.php?f=36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.  The Spring WebFlow 2.0 documentation has a chapter on upgrading, including a tool to convert your 1.0 flows to 2.0.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/spring-webflow-reference.html#upgrade-guide